# Why does Object.keys() return an Array of strings?

Tags: javascript, object, key

It took me quite some time to realize that `Object.keys()` return and Array of **strings** that correspond to the object keys. This is [well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#return_value) (but you have to read carefully :)).

My question is: **what are the (technical) reasons for the returned Array to be made of keys cast to a string?** (and not the keys themselves)

In my case the keys were integers, so I had to re-cast what `.keys()` returns through a `.map()`

Comment: Object keys are strings - always have been, always will be

Comment: _"In my case the keys were integers"_ - No. Only with an array or a `Map`/`WeakMap`

Comment: even if you use a number as a key ... it's still going to be a string ... `Object.keys({1:1}).forEach(x => console.log(typeof x))`

Comment: [Keyed collections - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections#object_and_map_compared): _"Traditionally, objects have been used to **map strings** to values. ... The **keys of an Object are Strings** or Symbols, ..."_

Comment: In the example to which you linked, the keys are `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`.  What integer values do you expect those to be and why?  In the majority of objects I've ever seen, property names are text.  Usually semantically meaningful words like `"name"` or `"address"`.  What integer values do you expect those to be and why?

Comment: Thanks to the comments pointing out that keys are always strings - good to know. It is disheartening to see downvotes instead of correcting me and helping to get a better grasp on the language...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my case the keys were integers

They were not.

Object property names can only be strings or Symbols ([ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections#object_and_map_compared)).

The numbers (JS doesn't have an integer data type) were converted to strings **when the property was created**, not when the property names were read.